# Is there a benefit to using nested LET formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested

Suppose I have the following LET statement in Excel:

```
=LET(simplifiedArray, LET(largeArray1, [formula for large array], 
                          largeArray2, [formula for another large array],
                          formula to get simplified array using largeArray1 and largeArray2),
calculation using simplifiedArray multiple times)
```

I do not need to use the variables largeArray1 or largeArray2 outside of the inner LET formula. I'm wondering if the above formula is better than:

```
=LET(largeArray1, [formula for large array], 
     largeArray2, [formula for another large array],
     simplifiedArray, formula to get simplified array using largeArray1 and largeArray2,
calculation using simplifiedArray multiple times)
```

In particular I'm wondering if Excel cleans up memory once it leaves the inner LET formula.  I can see this would be a huge advantage if largeArray1 and 2 are very big.

Would anybody know if this type of "garbage collection" happens?

Comment: Let calculates it's declared names separately, even if it's not used anywhere in the other calculations.